# Printing Json result with PHP

Tags: php, json

Im trying to print the json content of the following code but I dont seem to get it.
I have removed the API link for privacy concerns, but bare in mind the API and everything here should be functional, shut how do I print it out?
Code:

```
 $WSDL_URI = "URL"; 
    $client = new SoapClient($WSDL_URI);
    $result = $client->JsonContent();
```

Comment: `echo $result` ?

Comment: @Samir it says the $result is an object that cant be converted to string

Comment: `echo` will print a string. if you want object or array to be printed use `var_dump($result);` or `print_r($result);`

Comment: @Samir Thank you so much! It worked!
Edit: How do i mark your answer, first time using this website
And do you reckon i could loop through the results to retrieve certain data? I used to work with sql for that but can you give me any tips on how to get a certain field or value from json?

Comment: Yes, you can loop to get the data you need. Without seeing the structure of `$result` I can't say exactly on how would you retrieve a particular value. For example: if your object has person->name then we can retrieve it as `$result->person->name`. If your object has mutiple person with numeric index `$result[0]->person->name` will give the first person's name.